# How to build Multip-hop VPN using OpenVPN and two CentOS Servers?

Tags: centos, openvpn

I have two CentOS droplets. I want to create a scenario like this:

```
User(IP: 185.20.20.1) --> VPN1(Server1: 90.80.1.1) --> VPN2(Server2: 5.80.20.18) --> Google.com(assumes the user IP address is 5.80.20.18)
```

I know how to create a VPN using OpenVPN and a CentOS droplet. The final user IP address will be "90.80.1.1" on the above example. My question is, how to pass the traffic from Server1 to Server2 so that the final IP address becomes the last server which is Server2 (5.80.20.18)?

[image: Figure1: Multi-hop VPN Illustration]

*Figure1: Multi-hop VPN Illustration*

Comment: This is just a matter of proper routing setup. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov The problem is, I have no idea where to start. I have not done this before and have no experience. I also cannot find a tutorial on Google. Could you share any if you have?

Comment: Basically you build each tunnel individually, using different subnet for each. Then you configure routing, as usual, treating tunnel virtual  interfaces as ordinary network interfaces. I don't think there's a ready made tutorial, because those who invent such schemes usually know what they're doing, and those who don't know usually don't invent tricky schemes. // Sorry, I don't get your intentions, because ultimately static setup like this will only slow things down without any perceived benefit. When Tor or I2P uses routing like this it builds dynamic tunnels, that's the matter.